# How to denormalize array in JS

Tags: javascript, arrays, denormalization

I have a data set of the following form

```
let data = [
  {
    "id": {
      "primary": "A1"
    },
    "msg": 1
  }, {
    "id": {
      "primary": "A1"
    },
    "msg": 2
  }, {
    "id": {
      "primary": "B2"
    },
    "msg": 3
  }
]
```

I would like to transform it to

```
newData = [
  {
    "id": {
      "primary": "A1"
    },
    "items": [
      { "msg": 1 },
      { "msg": 2 }
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": {
      "primary": "B2"
    },
    "items": [
      { "msg": 3 }
    ]
  }
]
```

I think the method is something like the following, but am not sure how to check against `undefined` values in this case.

```
let newData = [];
for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
  if (newData[i]['id']['primary'] === data[i]['id']) newData.push(data[i]['id'])
  else newData[i]['items'].push(data[i]['msg'])
}
```

How can I transform the original data set to merge entries with a matching `primary id`?

Comment: JSON is JavaScript Object Notation. It is a string format to represent JavaScript objects. I see no `JSON.parse`, `JSON.stringify`, or anything else that indicates you are working with JSON.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could also solve this in a concise way via the [Array.reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) and [ES6 destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment):

```js
let data = [ { "id": { "primary": "A1" }, "msg": 1 }, { "id": { "primary": "A1" }, "msg": 2 }, { "id": { "primary": "B2" }, "msg": 3 } ]

let result = data.reduce((r, {id, msg}) => 
  ((r[id.primary] = r[id.primary] || { id, items: [] }).items.push({msg}), r), {})

console.log(Object.values(result))
```

In more readable format it is:

```js
let data = [ { "id": { "primary": "A1" }, "msg": 1 }, { "id": { "primary": "A1" }, "msg": 2 }, { "id": { "primary": "B2" }, "msg": 3 } ]

let result = data.reduce((r, {id, msg}) => {
  r[id.primary] = (r[id.primary] || { id, items: [] })
  r[id.primary].items.push({msg})
  return r
}, {})

console.log(Object.values(result))
```

The idea is to group by the `id.primary` and then once the grouping is done simply get the values via `Object.values`

Notice that this is one pass solution where you do not have to per each iteration do an `Array.find` against the current accumulator.

Comment: What does the `{id, msg}` syntax do in this context?

Comment: This is just ES6 object destructuring. I added a link to my answer.

Comment: Would `{id}, {msg}` be equivalent?

Comment: It would be sure but it is not a common thing these days :) It just adds extra chars etc. The main idea here is that you are no longer doing a loop and inside of it another ... this is a more performant solution.

Comment: Yes. Thank you Akrion!!

Comment: How would you say, "this array index" instead of `msg`? i.e. if `msg` was an abstraction for several keys.

Comment: The current array index is provided for you by the Array.reduce ... you can access it if you do `data.reduce((r, {id, msg}, i)` where the `i` would be the array index.

Comment: Ah, I see it now. I was looking for `data.reduce((r, {id, msg}, i, arr)`. The `let item = arr[i]`.

Comment: You're awesome. Thank you :)

Comment: Worth noting that this is referential; changing a property or value in `data` will change `result` as well. Of course, this may not really be an issue depending on use-case.

Answer (score 3):

One option would be to use [`.reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) to create a new array from the existing.

I've added comments to clarify.

```js
let data = [ { "id": { "primary": "A1" }, "msg": 1 }, { "id": { "primary": "A1" }, "msg": 2 }, { "id": { "primary": "B2" }, "msg": 3 } ];

let result = data.reduce((out,item) => {
  let {id, ...items} = item;                      //Separate the "id" and "everything else"
  let existing = out.find(({id}) => id.primary == item.id.primary); 

  existing                                        //have we seen this ID already?
    ? existing.items.push(items)                  //yes - add the items to it
    : out.push({ id: {...id}, items: [items]});   //no - create it
    
  return out;
  }, []);
  
console.log(result);
```

A couple notes:

- You may notice that I've set the ID using `id: {...id}`, despite the `id` already being an object. This is because using the existing `id` object would create a *reference*, whereas `{...id}` creates a shallow *copy*.
- I haven't specified the `msg` property anywhere. Instead, any properties that *aren't* `id` will be added to the `items` list *(example below)*.

  ```js
      let data = [ { "id": { "primary": "A1" }, "msg": 1, "otherStuff": "Hello World!" }, { "id": { "primary": "A1" }, "msg": 2, "AnotherThing": true }, { "id": { "primary": "B2" }, "msg": 3, "someOtherProperty": false } ];

      let result = data.reduce((out,item) => {
        let {id, ...items} = item;
        let existing = out.find(({id}) => id.primary == item.id.primary); 

        existing
          ? existing.items.push(items)
          : out.push({ id: {...id}, items: [items]});
          
        return out;
        }, []);
        
      console.log(result);
  ```

  That said, if you start to nest objects (other than ID), they will likely be included as references; `...items` is only a *shallow* copy.

  If such a case, consider something like [`JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(...))`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/122102/what-is-the-most-efficient-way-to-deep-clone-an-object-in-javascript) for a deep copy. Be sure to read the link though; there are caveats.

Comment: This looks good. Thank you for the help!! My actual data structure is a bit more complicated, so it's going to take me a minute to wrap my head around this...

Comment: @Matthew The overall gist is that your ID will be copied into the new object (as you showed in your question). Everything else will be copied over and lumped into the `items` portion for the corresponding ID.

Comment: Got it. Thank you!! :)